# What is the correct syntax for cloning a ntfs partition to a sparse file on another ntfs drive?

Tags: sparse-files, ddrescue

I have tried `ddrescue -v -v -S /dev/sda2 /media/mint/otherhdd/img  /media/mint/otherhdd/log` and `ddrescue -v -v -d -S /dev/sda2 /media/mint/otherhdd/img  /media/mint/otherhdd/log` but it does not work how i need.

sda2 is a 74 gb partition and i have about 200 MB of data. So from my understanding a sparse image file should be close to that. But dd tries from what i can see to add the free space to the file .
In its console output it is specified that sparse mode is on / "yes" .

I always interrupt the process with `ctrl+c`  some time after the img file reaches 3GB so i do not know if the file is supposed to implode AFTER it reaches 74 GB. Shouldn't this work?

Comment: Use `ntfsclone` which only copies the allocated sectors.

Comment: Hmmm....I was not aware that NTFS filesystem allowed sparse allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Sparse file is a property of a file on a file system. Some utilities can recognize those as such either directly or by using heuristics (basically scanning the contents for long enough string of zeros). To avoid any complications given by the relative strangeness (in the meaning of "non-nativeness") NTFS you are going to be better off by using `ntfsclone` (usually found in the `ntfsprogs` - or similarly named - package).

Store the NTFS partition into a file:

```
ntfsclone -s -o dev_sda2_image.img /dev/sda2
```

Restore the NTFS partition from a file:

```
ntfsclone -r -o /dev/sda2 dev_sda2_image.img
```

IIRC you should even be able to chain it in a pipe.